# How to correctly configure postgresql hostname in docker-compose

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, application.properties

I dockerized my java application. I can run this from intellij idea and it works great I can connect to localhost:8091. But when my friend tries to run my image he faces an error:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

As far as I understand the key to solve my problem is to configure correct database hostname in application.properties then recreate the image. But I cannot configure jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/agregator in my application.properties because of errors I face then I try to run my project. Building crashes because it cannot connect to my db by this url (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agregator).
now my application.properties looks like this:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agregator spring.datasource.username=postgres spring.datasource.password=pass spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

My question is, how can I configure my database hostname in order to be able to run my project in localhost and run it through the docker without getting any errors?

p.s. Could you please give me advice on how to solve this problem in windows without linux command line :)
p.p.s I know it's not right to pass credentials like I did.

Comment: Fix the original problem.  The error you report seems to be the error from your futile attempt to fix the original problem, not the error from the original problem itself.  Put things back the way they were before, then tell us what error you get from that.

Comment: What do you mean by fixing original problem?This is the same condition when i get an error, i just figured out that i need to fix hostname, i also figured out where to fix this.
i tried spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/agregator  instead of spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agregator but in vain.

My problem still is that i can't run docker container, it crashes because it can't connect to localhost:5432 database

Comment: Are you saying that even when you have it configured to connect to 'postgres', it still complains that it can't connect to 'localhost'?  In that case, it seems most likely that the configuration file you are changing is not the one being used.

Comment: No, i can't build my project if i configure postgres instead of localhost. That's why i can't create image with new hostname path. My question is how to configure hostname correctly to be able to connect both locally and via running docker container

Comment: And my question is, what error do you get?  "can't build my project" is not an error message.

Comment: It's quite a lot of messages:
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка при попытке подсоединения.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres

if i understand it correctly this happens because of my db has (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agregator) url and i'm trying to connect by (jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/agregator)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use a hyphen in a volume name on Windows.

```
volumes:
  - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

and

```
volumes:
  db-data:
```

This should work:

```
volumes:
  - "pgData:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

and

```
volumes:
  pgData:
```

Also, I doubt that you want to expose the DB to the outside world:

```
ports:
  - "5434:5432"
```

Your app also needs the variables for user+password:

```
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/agregator
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sitis
```